# I can commit docker images, but can not run this because jar file is not shown in command and that is why it does not found

Tags: java, spring, docker, intellij-idea, docker-machine

In Docker,  when I write command below, it created image. But it can not find jar file for running
this

[image]

it create image:

[image]

And here in run command, it does not find jar file:

[image]

and when I try 'docker ps-a', it seems that jar file is not shown
[image]

And here is my commands sequentially. I enter to corresponding directory in cmd. And write these

- docker run -dit openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
- docker container cp target/hello-world-rest-api.jar funny_noyce:/tmp
- docker container exec funny_noyce ls /tmp   (it shows the existence of jar file)
- docker container commit --change="CMD ["java","-jar","tmp/hello-world-rest-api.jar"]" funny_noyce in28min/hello-world-rest-api:manual2
- docker run -p 8080:8080 in28min/hello-world-rest-api:manual2
  I do it several times. But it did not work, each time. What can be problem here? Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the Dockerfile?

Comment: sorry, there is no docker file. I use the path of project

Comment: It's not possible since you cannot create an image without a Dockerfile...

Comment: What about with jar file? I see that in tutorial

Comment: So you grabbed a ready image from the Dockerhub, then you changed a parameter INSIDE of the docker image which has its own files? I think you are hoping to redirect it to your personal jar file but that is not how it works. It might be helpful to know what you are tying to achieve but maybe take a look at this https://javamondays.com/running-your-spring-boot-app-inside-of-docker/

Comment: Thanks for reply. But not actually, there are project in intellij, and i go to that directory, and enter these commands sequentially. Sorry, I do not include these command in advance, now i edit the question. I think that it would be more clear